# Install Gem from Github Branch?

Tags: rubygems, branch, github

In my gemfile I have this:

```
gem "authlogic", :git => "git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git", :branch => "rails3"
```

How do I install that as a gem so I can test it?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You don't need to build the gem locally. In your gemfile you can specify a github source with a ref, branch or tag.

```
gem 'rails', git: 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', ref: '4aded'
gem 'rails', git: 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '2-3-stable'
gem 'rails', git: 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', tag: 'v2.3.5'
```

Then you run `bundle install` or the short form is just `bundle`.

Read more about it here: http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#GIT

**Update:** There's [a github source identifier](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#GITHUB).

```
gem 'country_select', github: 'stefanpenner/country_select'
```

However, they warn against using it: `NOTE: This shorthand should be avoided until Bundler 2.0, since it currently expands to an insecure git:// URL. This allows a man-in-the-middle attacker to compromise your system.`

After Bundler 2.0, you can get around the above issue with this statement near the top of the Gemfile:

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
```

Comment: update from 2017, I couldn't get the GitHub source identifier to work but the :git => ref works fine

Comment: Maybe its Windows shenanigans, but with RubyInstaller 2.3 on Windows 10, I have this same setup for a gem I have that is unreleased, and I issue the `bundle install` command, RubyGems says its fetching the git repo, and its installed, but when I do `gem list gemname` it doesn't show up in my locally installed gems.

Comment: nvm, its because I'm expecting `bundle install` to install as though it were global, or for all rubygems. however, its doing it per project, or sometimes per user. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3070#issuecomment-46361014

Comment: At least for our environment, the `github:` identifier gives the `transmits data without encryption` warning that I'm looking to avoid.  Converting to a `git:` identifier with `https` might not be enough, as I also have a branch to specify.

Comment: Regarding installing with github source identifier: `NOTE: This shorthand should be avoided until Bundler 2.0, since it currently expands to an insecure git:// URL. This allows a man-in-the-middle attacker to compromise your system.` - per the [link you gave](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#GITHUB)

Answer (score 65):

1. Clone the Git repository.

   ```
   $ git clone git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
   ```
2. Change to the new directory.

   ```
   cd authlogic
   ```
3. Checkout branch

   ```
   $ git checkout -b rails3 remotes/origin/rails3
   ```
4. Build the gem.

   ```
   $ rake build gem
   ```
5. Install the gem.

   ```
   $ gem install pkg/gemname-1.23.gem
   ```

Comment: I needed to change 4. to "rake build" to build the gem.

Comment: Instead of 4. I had to use gem build name-of-file.gemspec  to build the gem rake build o rake gem did not work for me

Comment: Instead of 4 and 5 you can do "rake install"

Comment: Or straight from github: `gem 'rails', :github => 'rails', :branch => '5.0-stable'` - link: http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html

Comment: @Danny that would be `github: 'rails/rails'`

Comment: For me `gem build <gem-name>.gemspec` worked. I didn't have `rake` listed in the Gemfile. So `rake build gem` threw **rake is not part of the bundle. add it to gemfile**

Answer (score 5):

I have to modify @janic_'s answer to make it work.
Hope it will help other ruby noobs like myself.

1. Clone the Git repository.

   ```
   $ git clone git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
   ```
2. Change to the new directory.

   ```
   $ cd authlogic
   ```
3. Checkout branch

   ```
   $ git checkout -b rails3 remotes/origin/rails3
   ```
4. Install bundles

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```
5. Build the gem.

   ```
   $ rake build
   ```
6. Install the gem.

   ```
   $ gem install pkg/gemname-1.23.gem
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To update @Archonic answer, you need to replace the git protocol per the https protocol

```
fatal: remote error:
  The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
```

Therefore, you need to write:

```
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', ref: '4aded'
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '2-3-stable'
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', tag: 'v2.3.5'
```

Comment: If you read till the end of the accepted answer, it says you can use `git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }` to solve the https issue.