# install gem from specific branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Install Gem from Github Branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823492/install-gem-from-github-branch)

I have been following the guide from that thread.  When I get to step 4, rake gem , I get an error

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gem'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are using Jeweler which has a `rake build` task to build the gem.

You can check what rake tasks are available by doing `rake -T` or `rake -vT` (more verbose). If I do that in a gem's root directory that uses Jeweler I get:

```
rake build                    # Build gem
```

as an option.

I think you can also skip the manual install step by doing `rake install` too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to install jeweler:

```
sudo gem install technicalpickles-jeweler -s http://gems.github.com
```

Otherwise it won't build.