# uninitialized constant APN::Device (apn_on_rails for rails3 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I have followed [this tutorial](http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-send-iphone-push-notifications-in-rail) to configure [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails) but I am getting the following error message when I call my action:

```
uninitialized constant APN::Device
```

This is the line that produces the conflict:

```
device = APN::Device.create(:token => device_token)
```

As suggested [here](http://www.metabates.com/2009/07/31/apn-on-rails-0-3-0-released/), I have added a require 'apn_on_rails' in my environment.rb but nothing changed.

It seems that the gem apn_on_rails is only installed under gem/bundler, could that be the problem? If so, how can I install it if I have it in my gemfile like this:

```
gem 'apn_on_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

then how can I call something like sudo gem install 'apn_on_rails' ... to install that version?

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823492/install-gem-from-github-branch) and making a change to that solution

Clone the Git repository.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/natescherer/apn_on_rails.git
```

Change to the new directory.

```
cd apn_on_rails
```

Build the gem.

```
$ gem build apn_on_rails.gemspec
```

(Running that I got:

```
 Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: apn_on_rails
  Version: 0.3.1rails3
  File: apn_on_rails-0.3.1rails3.gem
```

Install the gem.

```
$ gem install apn_on_rails-0.3.1rails3.gem
```