# Error building gem from git branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, rubygems

I am following the instructions of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823492/install-gem-from-github-branch) to install a gem from git.

When I try to do I checkout of the branch I get:

```
mari@Black:~/Documents/apn_on_rails$ git checkout -b rails3 remotes/origin/rails3
fatal: git checkout: branch rails3 already exists
```

I also tried [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)  to download the branch and that works fine. But I still cannot build the gem. I get:

```
mari@Black:~/Documents/apn_on_rails$ rake build --trace
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- gemstub
/home/mari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/mari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/mari/Documents/apn_on_rails/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

I also tried `rake gem` but I get the same error. What can I do?

I am using rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by running `gem build apn_on_rails.gemspec` instead of `rake build` or `rake gem` as suggested in the instructions followed

Answer (score 0):

possibly you already have rails3 branch. Check this with git branch. 
If branch already exist try running same command without '-b'. It should work.

Comment: This is what I got:mari@Black:~/Documents/apn_on_rails$ git checkout rails3 remotes/origin/rails3
error: pathspec 'remotes/origin/rails3' did not match any file(s) known to git.  ANd I also tried it like this
mari@Black:~/Documents/apn_on_rails$ git checkout rails3
Already on 'rails3'