# gem install autotest-fsevent failing after update to macosx mavericks

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks

After update to Maveriks having problems installing gem `autotest-fsevent`

Here is the error I get;

```
Mellon:public lasdolphin$ sudo gem install autotest-fsevent
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing autotest-fsevent:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/lasdolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    extconf.rb:24:in `<main>': Darwin 13 is not (yet) supported (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lasdolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-        p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lasdolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-        p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.8/ext/fsevent/gem_make.out
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like you might need to reinstall the developer utilities from XCode.

Comment: Already did. Didn't help.

Comment: I've fixed this on Github, but can't push it to Rubygems right now due to credentials problems. Please install autotest-fsevent from Github until I've sorted this out.

Comment: I've just pushed the fix to Rubygems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This has been fixed in version 0.2.9 of autotest-fsevent**

It fails because of the following line in autotest-fsevent:

[SDK_VERSION    = { 9 => '10.5', 10 => '10.6', 11 => '10.7', 12 => '10.8' }[DARWIN_VERSION]](https://github.com/svoop/autotest-fsevent/blob/master/ext/fsevent/extconf.rb#L22)

Notice that there is no entry for Mavericks (10.9). You can temporarily fork the autotest-fsevent repo on github and add in the necessary entry for Mavericks:

`13 => '10.9'`

which seems to at least let it build. Then refer to your fork in your gemfile:

```
gem 'autotest-fsevent', git: 'https://github.com/your-username/autotest-fsevent'
```

If you're not using bundler, [install the gem from the branch directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823492/install-gem-from-github-branch).

Comment: I've just pushed the fix to Rubygems.

Answer (score 2):

1. Upgrade XCode from 5.0 to 5.0.1
2. Install the latest [Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October 2013](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)
3. Rebuild your ruby (in my case, I use rbenv, so I run `rbenv install 2.0.0-p247`)

The above steps solve my problem, hope it help!

Comment: Nope it didn't help.

    `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]`
but 
     `gem install autotest-fsevent`
keeps telling me
    `ERROR:  Error installing autotest-fsevent:
    `<main>': Darwin 13 is not (yet) supported (RuntimeError)`
But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I try to install the "Comand line tools (OS X Maveriks)" from XCode and from the site, without success.

In another post I found the workable solution for me, I found this command:

> xcode-select --install

This command download and install the command line tools in the right way I guess.

After that, I can install all my new gems without problem.

Comment: That is  what i'm getting
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0fcrbe750mb22d/Screenshot%202013-10-30%2009.22.25.png
hope this is temporary problem, will try later.

Comment: Hello @AndreyMurav'ev , The error is more close to be an internet access or connection access than your original problem with gems, are you behind some firewall or restricted internet access?

Comment: Nope this  issue was persistent, and everything  worked fine  on other  computer. Anyway after I've made a  fresh incrall of mavericks and  installed dev tools  via  Xcode-select --install, i'm getting this error 
`<main>: Darwin 13 is not (yet) supported (RuntimeError)`
anyway. Thanks  for tour help.