# Unable to install gem autotest-fsevent on Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks

It's been two days trying to install the gem autotest-fsevent, but i get this error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing autotest-fsevent:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/samolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:24:in `<main>': Darwin 13 is not (yet) supported (RuntimeError)

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/samolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/samolo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.8/ext/fsevent/gem_make.out
```

I tried this solution: "[gem install autotest-fsevent failing after update to macosx mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553436/gem-install-autotest-fsevent-failing-after-update-to-macosx-mavericks)", but nothing change. I also tried too put `gem "autotest-fsevent", "~> 0.2.8"` into Gemfile, but i get the same error.
May be a suggestion?
I using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed in version 0.2.9 of autotest-fsevent**

It fails because of the following line in autotest-fsevent:

[SDK_VERSION    = { 9 => '10.5', 10 => '10.6', 11 => '10.7', 12 => '10.8' }[DARWIN_VERSION]](https://github.com/svoop/autotest-fsevent/blob/master/ext/fsevent/extconf.rb#L22)

Notice that there is no entry for Mavericks (10.9). You can fork the autotest-fsevent repo on github and add in the necessary entry for Mavericks:

`13 => '10.9`

which seems to at least let it build. Then refer to your fork in your gemfile.

Comment: just an FYI their github seems to be up to date for Mavericks but the gem on rubygems seems to not be as up to date, so if you change your gemfile line to this `gem 'autotest-fsevent', git: 'https://github.com/svoop/autotest-fsevent.git'` it should work fine.

Comment: wish I could upvote @Jimmy comment more. that saved the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the latest version of Xcode for Mavericks 10.9 fixed my install problem for autotest-fsevent.