# How to install and edit a ruby gem from a debugging branch on GitHub

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to test a branch of a GitHub repo.

`gem install gemName` installs the master branch.

I've tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823492/install-gem-from-github-branch) without luck.

I don't how to use [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gem-install-branch/versions/0.0.3) either.

And how could I edit the gem afterwards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Gem from Github Branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823492/install-gem-from-github-branch)

Comment: @OneNeptune I've tried those answers before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a gem specifying a branch, eg:

```
gem "rack", git: "https://github.com/rack/rack.git", branch: "rack-1.5"
```

Reference: http://bundler.io/git.html

Comment: I get this error 
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command gem_Name,`

Answer (score 0):

Arturo's answer didn't work for me.

I had luck with this syntax:

```
gem install gem_name --branch branch_name
```